# when i run ''yum install php-pgsql" I got "You need to be root to perform this command." as an error . how to be the root

Tags: php, postgresql

I am to install php with postgres 
when I want to run "yum install php-pgsql" in ubuntu the message was 
"You need to be root to perform this command."
how to be the root?

I expect to install php with postgres

Comment: It is not the right forum, here is your response : https://askubuntu.com/questions/91598/how-do-i-login-as-root

Answer (score 2):

Add `sudo` for root permissions:

```
sudo yum install php-pgsql
```